# error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: isFinished)

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room, rx-java2

Using Room + rxJava, I want to add extra column to my database table "story" but not in the actual database, so I'm using "@Transient", which works like "@Ignore".

Also I have 2 data-model and 2 "Dao" accessing the db.
The "vocabulary" data-model works fine after adding:

```
@Transient
var status: Int? = 0
```

but when I want to add another column to my second data model "story" like this:

```
@Transient
var isFinished: Int? = 0
```

it gives me this error:

> error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or
> missing database (no such column: isFinished)

Here's the data models:

```
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.Ignore
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey


@Entity(tableName = "vocabulary")
data class  Vocabulary constructor(

@PrimaryKey
val id: Int?,
val range: String?,
val note: String?,
val word: String?,
val coding: String?,
val pronunciation: String?,
val examples: String?,
val lesson: Int?,
val lesson_order: Int?,
val definition: String?,
val persian: String?,
var favorited: Int?,
val viewed: Int?,
val is_read: Int?,
val pexa: String?,
val pexb: String?,
val pexc: String?
){
    @Transient
    var status: Int? = 0
}
```

second data-model:

```
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.Ignore
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey


@Entity(tableName = "story")
data class Story(

    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int?,
    val title: String?,
    val text: String?,
    val per_title: String?,
    val per_text: String?,
    val range: String?

){
    @Transient
    var isFinished: Int? = 0
}
```

and in the Dao I use it like this:

```
@Dao
interface IStoryDao {

    @Query("UPDATE story SET isFinished = 1 ")
    fun setFinished(): Completable
}
```

Answer (score 1):

But what do you expect?

`@Transient` like `@Ignore` allows to add field to Entity's class **without** adding corresponding column to Sqlite database. That means you can't use such fields in queries and the error message tells exactly about that:

> no such column: isFinished

Maybe you have some misunderstanding below?

> I want to add extra column to my database table "story" but not in the actual database

With `@Transient` you just add field to Kotlin data class and this field doesn't persist in database. I guess you don't have problem with `status` field, just because you don't use query with it.

Comment: thanks for your reply! it's so much clearer now!
now i see how i was using it wrong!
thanks man